# Download a package copy of Rosetta to manually transfer to another Mac without internet

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, rosetta, rosetta-2

I have an odd situation here — I need to get a copy of Rosetta (the translation program that let's x86 software run on Apple silicon Macs) onto a Mac that can't connect to the internet (yet). I'm hoping someone knows how to download a .zip of it that I can use a hard drive to port to the internet-less computer.

Kind of a long story, but I recently reformatted an Apple Silicon Mac and used migration assistant to clone a copy of my work setup onto it, only the profiles in this employeer build require activation via the corporate network before you can connect to the internet. Normally this is done via the VPN client that comes pre-installed on their machines, only, I can't run that VPN client because it's x86 and the computer is Apple Silicon... but I can't install Rosetta in order to run it either because I can't connect to the internet.

Thus I need to download Rosetta on another computer, put it on a hard drive, and open it on the first computer. Just can't seem to find a file-copy of Rosetta anywhere is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install Rosetta on an Apple Silicon Mac with internet:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
   ```
2. Run the following script to find the installation folder:

   ```
   grep "RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg" /var/log/install.log
   ```

   The installation folder path will be something like:

   ```
   /var/folders/f5/_hdu19hcuin1ckjnqkjcndwkcnadskjnckjqwn/T/OAHSoftwareUpdate/RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg
   ```
3. Go to the installation folder, copy the `RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg` file and install it on the Mac that is offline.